# Notation in a neutron star superfluidity

Tags: nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry, superfluidity

In this article "Neutron Star and Superfluidity", by Ka Wai Lou:
http://guava.physics.uiuc.edu/~nigel/courses/569/Essays_Fall2010/Files/lo.pdf
symbols as $^1S_0$ and $^3 P_2$ are shown, but I not sure if they mean electron configuration or something else, because neutrons in that case wouldn't have electrons, so it wouldn't make sense. If anyone is familiar with that let me know.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 2):

This notation gives
$$
^{2s+1}L_J
$$
for the neutrons that form Cooper pairs. Orbital angular momentum is given as $S,P,D$ for $L=0,1,2$. Since neutrons are identical fermions pairing in the $s$-wave ($L$=0, symmetric wave function) implies spin zero (anti-symmetric) and $p$-wave pairing implies spin one.

Answer (score 1):

These are the pairing specifications of the cooper pairs. The neutrons are spin 1/2 particles and can therefore form pairs with total spin 0 for instance, therefore the "S", or pairs with total spin 1 ("P").